# How to interact With each button

Tags: android

I have created an array of buttons..now i want to interact with each button..so that when i click a particular button it will show the text of that button on my text view..so please suggest me for that.. i am sending my code where i have created an array of button..

```
public boolean initDay()
{
    LinearLayout layoutVertical = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.liVLayout);
    LinearLayout rowLayout=null;

    LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,1);
    for (int i = 0; i<6; i++) 
    {
       rowLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
       rowLayout.setWeightSum(7);
       layoutVertical.addView(rowLayout,param);
        for(int j=0;j<7;j++)
        {
            pBtnDay[i][j]=new Button(this);
            rowLayout.addView(pBtnDay[i][j],param);
            pBtnDay[i][j].setClickable(true);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setOnClickListener()` for every object in loop:

```
pBtnDay[i][j].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{});
```

Nothing special. Hope this helps.

Comment: is it possible to open the device compose editor on click of each button

Comment: @Anshuman, sorry, didn't understand your question? What is device compose editor?

Comment: Actually i dont know the exact word.. as on click of EditTextBox an editor open automatically for type..so is it posible to open that type editor on click of button

Comment: You can implement a dialog with an EditText inside and show it on a button's click. Check the link below to see how it can be done:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: is type editor occurs..you get my point.actually when i want to type a new message than a type editor open for typing message..so i only want that type editor..can you please explain me with an example..if you are free

Answer (score 0):

```
 pBtnDay[i][j].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){

                   v.getText();//it contains button level
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can interact with each button using this code :

```
for(int j=0;j<7;j++)
        {
            pBtnDay[i][j]=new Button(this);
            rowLayout.addView(pBtnDay[i][j],param);
            pBtnDay[i][j].setClickable(true);
            //add a listener for each button 
            pBtnDay[i][j].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                  Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "text of button is "+pBtnDay[i][j].getText(),4000).show();
            });
        }
```

Comment: try to declare your i and j as a global variables